# Rest api return error code 406 not acceptable

Tags: c#, api

I am trying to use webshipper api but getting error code 406 not acceptable

here is my code

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://bascrm.api.webshipper.io/v2/rate_quotes");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.Accept = "Application/vnd.api+JSON";
    request.ContentType = "application/vnd.api+json";
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token + "");
```

after some google about this error i have added this code but still i am getting same error

```
WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = request.Headers;
    myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Language:da");
    myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Language", "en;q=0.8");
```

Comment: Well, the [main page of the WebShipper documentation](https://docs.webshipper.io/) says the content type must be `application/json`, so your code is already wrong.

Comment: @John at starting i am using application/json but getting error media type then i have change content -type

Comment: Maybe post the media type error and the code you were trying first. Did you try to use Fiddler? It can help you get more insights than just debugging. You can see the request and response in more details.

Comment: @ZeinSleiman i heve tried postman but due to content type application/vnd.api+json its not supporting

Comment: Error 406 generally indicates that something is wrong with acceptable values requested by client. Can you try changing accept type to some other value

Comment: @ajaygandhi i have tried  application/json but get same error also webshipper have confirmed me that they are returning datatype application/vnd.api+json